# Apex component like HTML component <legend>

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

Does any Apex component exist like the `<legend>My legend here : </legend>` tag in HTML?

I don't find any component like this on the Visual Force API.

Comment: Probably you are talking about `HTML` `legend`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Post updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>My legend</legend>
</fieldset>
```